# Webservice Security - what is enough?

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I am looking to expose a Web Service which can be called by multiple clients to retrieve transactional data. Each calling client will retrieve a different subset of data.

We are hosting the Webservice in Websphere 7 - the external webservice is essentially a proxy to the real WS running on our ESB platform.

Currently I have the following security in place:

1) WS-Security username/password sent in the header (plantext). This is authenticated against our custom repository (the repository is in-use elsewhere and has been security tested).

2) HTTPS

3) Restricting calling IPs via firewall

4) Payload data is PGP encrypted using the clients public key

Is this secure "enough"? I'm pretty sure the payload data is secure, but I'm not completely sure if the access mechanism is 100% secure? We are using what is built-in to IBM Websphere for #1.

Comment: can you tell me what is a header is? and how they are used in webservices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as your are using **HTTPS** you don't have to worry about sending the passwords in plaintext. So as long as your authentication works properly (you say the repo was security tested) this is quite secure.

Additionally you have encrypted payload using **PGP**, which is really secure - at least as long as all parties handle their keys with the needed care.

*--> What you're describing sounds fairly solid to me, especially with the asynchronous encryption of PGP which is basically not attackable (unless you consider social engineering).*

Maybe a last thought (but I guess you don't need this advice):
I don't know about Websphere, but in other application servers or ESBs (e.g. JBoss) there are some admin tools activated per default which tend to be freely accessible via the web (just google for */jmx-console* ...). Make sure to secure those with passwords or deactivate them if need be.

Comment: can you tell me what is a header is? and how they are used in webservices?

Answer (score 1):

For me it is more than enough. The only additional thing I can think about is using temporary passwords. See RSA for details.

Answer (score 1):

Is the subset of data which is returned by the service linked to the authenticated client identity, or is the returned set of data determined by a parameter which gets passed in?

Comment: The Username/Password combo is authenticated in our Repo, and if this is successful, the data returned is based on this "username" which is later mapped to a "real" client.

Comment: Everything looks solid, I would probably spend some time on automated tests to ensure that it stays that way, making sure that connection attempts fail as expected. Also good for deployment, if you have a quick way to determine that the system is setup to require SSL, and not just allow SSL, etc.